# Visualforce emailTemplate

Tags: visualforce, email-template

Please help me to get one of the following values based on True/False in VF Email Template.

I need to display a value/message based on true or false of this if

```
{!if(relatedTo.subject__r.name='OpportunitySale Salect',true,false)
```

- if it is true then "Here you can get driver information!"
- If it is false then "Here you can get driver's state information"

`<apex:outputtext rendered="{!if(relatedTo.subject__r.name='OpportunitySale Salect',true,false)}">`

Answer (score 1):

Why not replace `true` and `false` in your formula with the strings you provided for both cases? You can also create two `outputText` tags, each with it's own rendering condition. So if one is rendered the other isn't:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!condition1}" value="{!text1}"></apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText rendered="{!condition2}" value="{!text2}"></apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:outputText
   value="{!IF(relatedTo.subject__r.name = 'OpportunitySale Salect',
              'Here you can get driver information!',
              'Here you can get driver's state information')}"/>
```

Note that dynamically setting the value property of an apex component isn't supported for all components, like `inputField` or `outputField`.